# Update appsettings.json values in a WorkerService

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, config, worker-service

I'm trying to build a WorkerService and I'm using an appsetings.json file to store and read all my configurations. However, I'm looking for a way to update these values in execution time.

I'm currently using IOptions pattern like so,

```cs
Program.cs

       public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                IConfiguration configuration = hostContext.Configuration;
                services.Configure<SomeClass>(configuration.GetSection(nameof(SomeClass)));
            }
```

And I'm able to retrive values like so,

```cs
private readonly SomeClass config;

public Foo(IOptionsSnapshot<SomeClass> config;)
{
   this.config = config.Value;
}

public void DoSomething()
{
  var someValue = config.SomeValue; /// This values never update.
}
```

However, all properties of my SomeClass get never updated !

As I said, it's a WorkerService, so I'm well aware that IOptionsSnapshot interface is not working. So, I'm trying to find a way to trigger an snpashot in someway to read this appsettings.json again and update this values or another approach to update these values in execution time.

Comment: Did you tried IOptionMonitor ?

Comment: Yep. I tried that too with no results. This IOptionMonitor not working and neither IOptionsSnapshot.

Comment: You need to show more code. Are these objects singletons?

Comment: You can refer to my reply in this thread: [How to save the updates I made to appsettings configurations back to the appsettings.json file programmatically.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/609232/how-to-save-the-updates-i-made-to-appsettings-conf.html)

Comment: Yes, this answer sounds more helpful, for sure. Whoever, it's not what I'm looking for... I just want to read the current appsettings.json values and that's it, no more!! I'm not looking for update these values programatically actually... But sure, this answer sounds more like a work aorund solution.  Problem, it's that I'm working with a long time running task.

Comment: "I just want to read the current appsettings.json values and that's it,", you can refer to this article to read the content in the appsettings.json file.: [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0). Besides, you can also read the appsetting.json file content, then deserialize the json string and convert it to the Object.